# Azcopy source and destination conflicts

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I am confused about how azcopy  interprets the blobs

My source URL has files under ***"staging"*** "folder".

My destination is supposed to receive these files under ***"staging/outputtestfinal"***

However, azcopy is copying the blobs under ***"staging/outputtestfinal/staging"***

Why the second ***staging*** in my destination ?

I tried to *** https://myurlsource/staging/* but then the output is staging/outputtestfinal/staging/*

So a folder as "*" as created..  Really ? How I do a simple thing like this ?

```
azcopy copy "https://myurlsource/staging/" "https://myurldestin.blob.core.windows.net/staging/outputtestfinal/" --include-pattern '*.json' --recursive=true
```

Comment: Is "https://myurlsource/staging/" another storage account? or what. Source url "staging" means nothing. It may be just an endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `azcopy` to copy from one blob storage location to another, it will try to retain the folder structure relative to the source URL provided. This is why you are observing that behavior.

If your source URL is `https://myurlsource/staging/`, and you have a blob in there named `file1.json`, and you are copying it to `https://myurldestin.blob.core.windows.net/staging/outputtestfinal/`, the destination path becomes `https://myurldestin.blob.core.windows.net/staging/outputtestfinal/staging/file1.json`.

To avoid this, you can try the following:

**Use wildcard `*` without trailing slash**:
This tells `azcopy` to consider only the blobs directly under the `staging` virtual directory but not the directory itself.

```
azcopy copy "https://myurlsource/staging/*" "https://myurldestin.blob.core.windows.net/staging/outputtestfinal/" --include-pattern '*.json' --recursive=true
```

Answer (score 0):

> So a folder as "*" as created.. Really ? How I do a simple thing like  this

In my environment, my source container looks like you.

**Portal:**
[image]

To copy the destination you need to use a wildcard like **`*`** parameter to copy only files and it will exclude the folder.

From my side container is in **`private`** so I used SAS token.

**Command:**

```
azcopy copy "https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net/test/staging/*?sas-token" "https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net/test1/staging/outputtestfinal?sas-token" --include-pattern '*.json' --recursive=true
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Destination:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Transfer data to or from Azure Files by using AzCopy v10 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-files#use-wildcard-characters)